# Does the Django ORM have a construct defined that generates tables from each row under a specified column from a given table?

Tags: python, database, django, orm, django-models

Does the Django ORM have a construct defined that generates tables from each row under a specified column from a given table?

Example:
Suppose we have the following table.

```
Table: Person
id|name  |age
-------------
1 |John  |60      
2 |Isaac |24    
3 |Fred  |50      
4 |Will  |35
```

Now I want an object that creates a table from each row under `name` in `Person`. For the `John` and `Isaac` entries this would get me:

```
Table: John
id|name  |age_diff
------------------
1 |Isaac |36
2 |Fred  |10
3 |Will  |25

Table: Isaac
id|name  |age_diff
-------------------
1 |John  |36
2 |Fred  |26
3 |Will  |11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. In stock django tables are created by 'syncdb' command and its ORM does not handle dynamic addition or modification of tables.

Answer (score 1):

Django's ORM cannot create tables for you, as far as I know. You could do that via raw SQL statements:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
name = 'John'
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE '+name+'(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\
                name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, age_diff int NOT NULL,\
                PRIMARY KEY(id))')
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

But that's quite ugly. I think at least with your example it makes no sense to create these extra tables. Seems like a huge waste of storage without any gain. You could create the age differences just as well in Python code at the time you need them. That would also be a lot more intuitive.